# How to import a sketch file into NX programmatically via visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, sketching

I need to import sketches into NX, this sketch is a 2D sketch, and it can be in any geometric shape, I have no idea how it will look like, since it's up to the customer. This sketch is supposed to serve as the cross-section of the object. After I have this sketch, I am supposed to extrude it and create the object.
Below is a program which I have written for another purpose, I've left a gap in my code, because I believe that I should insert something into it in order to call out a sketch, yet I have no idea what I should write into the gap. Can anyone kindly tell me what should be written in the gap in order to call out the sketch? Thank you very much!

```
Option Strict Off
Imports System
Imports NXOpen
Module Points_01
     Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
              'Declare working part of the NX session
       Dim theSession As Session = Session.GetSession()
       Dim workPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Work




              'Create a section
              Dim circ As NXOpen.Section = workPart.Sections.CreateSection(ctol, dtol, atol)
              Dim helpPoint As New NXOpen.Point3d(X,Y,Z)
              Dim nullObj As NXOpen.NXObject = Nothing
              Dim noChain As Boolean = False
              Dim createMode As NXOpen.Section.Mode = Section.Mode.Create
              ' Create rules to add the circle to the section
              Dim circl As NXOpen.CurveDumbRule = workPart.ScRuleFactory.CreateRuleBaseCurveDumb({disk0,disk1})
              circ.AddToSection({circl}, disk0, nullObj, nullObj, helpPoint, createMode, noChain)
              circ.AddToSection({circl}, disk1, nullObj, nullObj, helpPoint, createMode, noChain)
              Dim builder = workPart.Features.CreateExtrudeBuilder(Nothing)
              builder.Section = circ
              'Define the direction of the Extrude
              Dim origin As New NXOpen.Point3d(X,Y,Z)
              Dim axisZ As New NXOpen.Vector3d(0,0,1)
              Dim updateOption = SmartObject.UpdateOption.DontUpdate
              builder.Direction = workPart.Directions.CreateDirection(origin, axisZ, updateOption)
              builder.Limits.StartExtend.Value.RightHandSide = "0"
              builder.Limits.EndExtend.Value.RightHandSide = "50"
              Dim pegs As NXOpen.Features.Extrude = builder.CommitFeature
              builder.Destroy
              'Get the displayable object of the Extrude feature
               Dim bodies As NXOpen.Body() = pegs.GetBodies
              ' Change its color to color red (186)
              bodies(0).Color = 186
              'Show object
              bodies(0).RedisplayObject
     End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: OH NO! It should be Option Strict On.

Comment: Okay I’ll make this change, May I ask what else should I write into my code in order to let a sketch run?